# How to have local echo on with `screen` command?

Tags: gnu-screen, tty, serial-port

I tried

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB1 9600,echo
```

but I still don't see what I type.

Comment: Use minicom, instead.

Comment: supposing that the device at `/dev/ttyUSB1` understands the AT Hayes command set, try typing `ATE1` followed by Enter.